# cocos2d - CCActionTween doesn't work

Tags: xcode, animation, path, cocos2d-iphone, action

I have roundPath and BoxPath and I would like to do:

`id modifyPath = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:2 key:@"path" from:roundPath to:boxpath];`
 but I have the error "incompatible type of argument 3 of 'actionWithDuration:key:from:to:' Ho w can I solve this please ? sorry for my english I'm french :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that "path" is a CGPoint type. In that case you can't use CCActionTween because it only works on built-in data types like BOOL, char, int, float, double but not C structs. CGPoint is a C struct defined as {float x; float y;}.

You can't use CCActionTween with path.x and path.y either. That's because you can't do this in Objective-C:

```
node.position.x = 10; // ERROR
```

You could however subclass and add two float properties myX and myY. You can tween both individually and assign them to the position in an update method every frame:

```
self.position = CGPointMake(myX, myY);
```